# Open Source alternative to Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: authentication, openid, token, identity, claims-based-identity

I was wondering what alternatives exists for seting up a federated token based security service.

And also how does it compare with a regular OpenId server.

Any literature on the subject would be more than welcome (I'm just getting into the subject)

Answer (score 2):

WIF deals mostly with SAML tokens and WS-Federation (websites) based identity federation. For other alternatives (OAuth, OpenId) there are various frameworks. One of them is [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/).

If your solution will be SAML based, I wouldn't bother too much with anything but WIF, unless you have a good reason (e.g. you are not running on Windows).

Comment: that's the case, I'm looking for an open source, multi-platform solution